# I have a checkBox and I want to get that data from database.What should I use whether getInt(boolean); or what.Can ayone suggest me the right code

Tags: java, jpanel, jcheckbox

I have a checkbox in a panel.If I click in that checkBox it should be saved.Iam not knowing what should I use.Can anyone suggest me with the right code.Thanks in advance.
                Here is my code.
                my checkbox name is--check; 
                my checkbox value is---checkvalue; 
                my database key is----abc;

```
            Boolean selected=checkvalue.getInt(boolean);  
                    if(selected==null){
                        abc.setcheckValue(null);
                    }else{
            abc.setcheckvalue(selected.getInt(boolean);

Here I want to use other code instead of getInt(boolean).Can anyone suggest
```

Comment: try to find the dataType of abc in your database schema. That will give your answer.

Comment: `boolean selected = checkvalue.isSelected();` maybe?

Comment: it is java.lang.boolean only @Rahul

Comment: I wil check once @Jan